# Add role to user after joining organic group with rules

Tags: rules, organic-groups

I'm trying to add a user role to a user who has become a member of a group. The workflow is like this:

- User requests to join group.
- Request is approved by group administrator.
- User is a member of the group.
- User gets an additional role.

I've tried to make a rule which would be able to do this, but although all the settings seem correct after joining the group the user doesn't get the additional role. See below a screenshot of my rule settings:

[image: Screenshot of my rule]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, so started a bounty on it.

Comment: @John Have you solved your problems?

Answer (score 2):

Now your Rule runs after user requests membership. But you should run it after OG membership was approved.
I prepared Rule which adds role “member” after membership was approved or if it was added by admin (auto-approved). Here is export (`4` is id of my drupal role “member”):

```
{ "rules_after_add_user_to_group" : {
    "LABEL" : "After add user to group",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "test" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "og" ],
    "ON" : [ "og_user_insert", "og_user_approved" ],
    "IF" : [ { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "og-membership:state" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "user_add_role" : { "account" : [ "account" ], "roles" : { "value" : { "4" : "4" } } } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
 [image]

**Tip:** you can enable Rules debug (page `admin/config/workflow/rules/settings`) to see when your rules are executed.

Comment: Hi Kalabro. Thank you for your awnser! I set it up that way, but the user does not get the role. I was able to fix it by adding a function to a custom module and add the role using custom php code. Ill post the dirty solution here.

Comment: PS. I asked my question here, more detailed than this question: http://drupal.org/node/1866278
If you debug $account, you see the role is added, but simply not saved, or overwritten by something.

Comment: @John I have commented your question on Drupal.org. Please, look at this: [#1](http://drupal.org/node/1866278#comment-6855884)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue (that why I started a bounty).

I solved it this way.

I added a function to a custom module. You can simple create your own module by making a new folder in /sites/all/modules with two files:

yourname_module.info ->>

```
name = "Custom Functions"
description = "Allows execution of custom code for the website"
core = 7.x
package = "yourname_customs"
version = 7.x-1.x
```

yourname.module

```
<?php 
function yourname_add_role_to_user($uid, $role_name) {

    $user = user_load($uid);

    if ($user === false || !isset($user->uid) || !is_array($user->roles)) {
        //Display an ugly error when user is not set correctly
        exit('$user is not set correctly <pre>' . print_r($user, true) . "</pre>");
    }

    //Get the user roles
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);

    if ($rid != FALSE) {
        $new_role[$rid] = $role_name;

        // Add new role to existing roles.
        $all_roles = $user->roles + $new_role;

        //Delete all user roles from DB
        db_delete('users_roles')
                ->condition('uid', $user->uid)
                ->execute();

        //Insert all user roles in DB
        $query = db_insert('users_roles')->fields(array('uid', 'rid'));
        foreach (array_keys($all_roles) as $rid) {
            if (!in_array($rid, array(DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID, DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID))) {
                $query->values(array(
                    'uid' => $user->uid,
                    'rid' => $rid,
                ));
            }
        }
        $query->execute();
    } else {

        //Display an ugly error wen role not found
        exit("Could not find role " . htmlspecialchars($role_name) . "<br/>
              Vald roles: <pre>" . print_r($roles, true) . "</pre>");
    }
}
```

Then goto your modules and enable "Custom Functions".

Make sure you have module custom php code enabled.

Then instead of action add user to role in rules, add: run custom php code and enter:

```
yourname_add_role_to_user($account->uid, "Members");
header("Location: /admin/people");
exit;
```

This adds the user to the role, and stops the script. If you don't stop the script, the role is not saved. 
And I needed to add a module because `user_save` does not work when executed in `custom php code`.

So, I know it is very ugly, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OG do you run ?

This is a know bug that have been fixed with Organic Group 2.4+ ([see bug page](https://drupal.org/node/1816800)).

If you are already running a 2.3 or lower version of OG the updgrate should be straightforward. If you are running OG 1.x, you can find more details on the [update process from OG 1.5 to 2.4+](https://drupal.org/node/1839652)